# Kendo UI panelBar content doesnt compile Angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, compilation

i i have a kendo UI panelBar, and i want to load data dynamically. I want inside panelBar option to have a template that use Angular. I have this part of code but this doesnt work.

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/PDFEditor/GetPDFDocumentInfo',
        params: { fileId: fileId }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.test = "My name is: <h1>Bond, James Bond </h1>";

        var tml = '<div id="testId"></div>';

        $scope.pdfInfo = response.data;

        $scope.appendToPanelBar([{
            text: 'Info',
            content: tml
        }]);

        document.getElementById("testId").innerHTML = "<p ng-bind-html=\"test\"></p> {{test}}";


    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        //todo
        console.error('todo error handling');
    });
```

I also tried without to get element by id and add directly to content: '{{test}}'. Seems that AngularJS doesn't compile this template.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution!!

```
        $scope.test = "My name is: <h1>Bond, James Bond </h1>";

        var tml = '<div id="testId"></div>';
        var data = $compile('<p>{{test}}</p>')($scope);
        console.log(data)
        $scope.pdfInfo = response.data;

        $scope.appendToPanelBar([{
            text: 'Info',
            content: tml
        }]);

        document.getElementById("testId").append(data[0]);
```

cheers!